# Double dispatching fails for an InputMap in C++ - codes reduced to simplicity

Tags: c++, polymorphism, handler, double-dispatch

Hello in one of my current projects I want to implement an InputMap. So I have an abstract input

```
//Input.h
namespace INPUT {
class InputMap;
class Input {
public:
    Input();
    virtual ~Input();
    virtual void Dispatch( InputMap * pMap ) = 0;
};
}
```

and an InputMap

```
//InputMap.h
namespace INPUT {
class InputMap {
public:
    InputMap();
    virtual void HandleInput( INPUT::Input & anInput ) {
    }
    virtual ~InputMap();
};
}
```

so far so good - no functionality here. Now I derive my first real Input from my abstract input class:

```
//StringInput.h
#include "Input.h"
#include "InputMap.h"
#include <string>

class StringInput : INPUT::Input {
public:
    StringInput();
    virtual ~StringInput();
    void Dispatch(INPUT::InputMap * pMap)
    {
        pMap->HandleInput( *this );
    }
    void SetMessage(std::string message);
    std::string GetMessage() const;
private:
     std::string m_message;
};
```

and here is my derived InputMap

```
//MyInputMap.h
#include "InputMap.h"
#include "StringInput.h"

class MyInputMap: public INPUT::InputMap {
public:
    MyInputMap();
    void HandleInput( StringInput & anInput );
    void HandleInput( INPUT::Input & anInput );
    virtual ~MyInputMap();
};
```

and here is the test:

```
//main.cpp
MyInputMap map;
StringInput input;
input.SetMessage("Test");
input.Dispatch(&map);
```

of course I expect that `input.Dispatch(&map)` invokes `map.HandleInput(StringInput input)`, but unfortunately the default handler is always invoked. Did I program this pattern wrong? Thanks guys, I have been staring my code forever, but I don't see it.

Comment: I think you forgot an `&` in your final paragraph.

Comment: Be careful with `INPUT`. You may star finding clashes the macros. convention dictates that macros are all uppercase so it is best avoided.

Comment: actually I think i just got around this: I just added a Dispatch(MyInputMap * pMap) to my class StringInput : INPUT::Input and now I seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Basically, the issue is that virtual function are statically bound (ironic), so the solution is to declare all `HandleInput` (for every single type of `Input`) in `InputMap`.

```
class InputMap {
public:
    InputMap();
    virtual void HandleInput(StringInput&) = 0;
    virtual void HandleInput(IntInput&) = 0;
    virtual ~InputMap();
};
```

Note: the convention is to use pure virtual methods, so that no derived class forgets from overriding one.

Of course, this causes an issue of dependencies. Fortunately, you can forward declare the "real" input types in the header containing `InputMap`.

There are more complicated variations (search for Acyclic Visitor), but you should not need it right now :)

Comment: Whichever way you skin this cat, you somehow always have to know the concrete types from the start... The acyclic visitor may be a bit more maintainable, at the expense of going through a list of dynamic casts until one succeeds.

Comment: @Kerrek: yes, that's why I usually bite the bullet and just use the typical `Visitor`.

Comment: actually I think i just got around this: I just added a Dispatch(MyInputMap * pMap) to my class StringInput : INPUT::Input and now I seems to work. This means my BaseClasses - both InputMap and Input are completely free of the derived types. Does this make sense in your experience?

Comment: @chris: unfortunately, it won't work if you have a function as such: `void dispatch(InputMap& map, Input& i) { map.Dispatch(i); }`.

Comment: ah I see - well, at least I am happy, that I can limit my mentioning of the concrete InputMap (i.e. `MyInputMap` ) to the concrete inputs (i.e. `StringInput`) and I do not have to taint my abstract base class `Input` with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function lookup and overload resolution is performed on the *static type*. So when you say `pMap->HandleInput(*this)` in `StringInput::Dispatch()`, this always finds the `InputMap::HandleInput(Input &)` overload, because `pMap` is of static type `InputMap`. This is then dispatched dynamically to the override `MyInputMap::HandleInput(Input &)`.

One way to overcome this is to add dynamic dispatch inside the (unique) `HandleInput()` function which determines the dynamic type of argument at runtime.